# Blazor Pass List of NavItems to NavMenu as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have the normal NavMenu and added a Parameter

```cs
[Parameter]
public List<NavItem> navItems {get, set;}
```

My Nav Item:

```cs
[Parameter]
  public string DisplayName {get, set;}

[Parameter]
  public string Href {get, set;}
```

So now in the MainLayout I want to add the **NavMenu** and add the **List of NavItems with Parameters**.

If I create the List of NavItems and assign the parameters I got the warning BL0005.

How can I do it the right way? (Not ignoring/disabling the warning)

Thanks

Comment: Hint: `RenderFragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a List of NavItems. Use a list of DisplayName/HRef pairs (ViewModels) instead.

The lifecycle of Blazor components is (should be) managed by Blazor. Everytime you do something like `new NavItem()` you are doing it wrong.

So create a ViewModel for your menu.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the `List` in NavMenu to `List<RenderFragment>` and then define them like:

`navItems.Add(@<a href="dummy.com">Test 1</a>);`

And use them like:

```
@foreach (var navItem in navItems)
{
    @navItem
}
```